# Unity3d Prime31 Google Play Game Services Tutorial

Tags: unity-game-engine, google-play-services, prime31

Does anyone know of any good resources on the web to get the Prime31 Google Play Game Services Plug in to work with Unity3D?

Its been 3 days, I just don't seem to be making any progress testing Game Play Services in my game.

I am using the SHA1 from the ~/.android/debug.keystore - which I believe is the the right SHA1 that the unsigned version uses.  I also tried using the published build in order to get the Game Center to come up.

I tried the Prime31 documentation, but that doesnt seems to be helping.
I also believe my app is correctly setup in the Game Service area of the Developer Console.

Any information would be great.

Thank you.

Comment: Could you show us some code or some more information so we can help you better?

Comment: please elaborate a bit, im thinking about buying this package myself in the next few days

Comment: Hi Fabio, hopefully you get this message. It's definitely a challenge getting it working.  I was wondering **what do you mean by the SHA1** you mention below?  You say you got the SHA1 from the keystore.  But what do you do with it???  I was not aware you have to use that anywhere in the GPG package?  Could you please tell me -- thanks!

Comment: forgot to @fabio "at" your nickname there, hope you get the messages!  ciao

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turned out that after importing the game center package , I ended up with two manifest files. I had the Prime[31] AdMob already in the project, which comes with a manifest file.
By the way this is normal.

After talking to the their support service they directed me to use the "Generate AndroidManifest.xml file..." under their prime[31] drop down menu inside Unity3D.  This merges the two files into a single manifest.  That problem got solved.

I also had to upgrade to the latest files, by downloading them manually, from the Prime[31] web site.

After this two steps I was able to get the Game Center to work properly.

I hope it will help[image], I am posting my interaction with the Prime[31] support

[image]